# Add value to hidden value by onclick checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with some input checkboxes. For example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_1" id="felhasznal_1" onclick="felhasznal(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_2" id="felhasznal_2" onclick="felhasznal(this)">
 <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_3" id="felhasznal_3" onclick="felhasznal(this)">
```

I have hidden value for a form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="felhasznalas" value="">
```

My form is named like this:

```
 <form method="post" name="ujpartner_ceg" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ujpartner_ceg">
```

And I want to add a masked id for the value of felhasznalas. But I have 2 forms with the same inputs, so that's why I named the forms, and I want to access to them by getelementByid using the form name.

Here is my javascript (generated by php):

```
function felhasznal() {
document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value = '|x|';

if (document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznal_1').checked) {
document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value = document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value + '1|x|';
}
if (document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznal_2').checked) {
document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value = document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value + '2|x|';
}
if (document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznal_3').checked) {
document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value = document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById('felhasznalas').value + '3|x|';
}
}
```

What did i do wrong?

EDIT: I get this error:
TypeError: document.ujpartner_ceges is not a function.

NOTICE: I have a form with the same inputs named ujpartner_magan!

Comment: what do you mean by masked id? and its better to catch the elements by type or id. form name may mislead you

Comment: What is the result of your code? Error message? Nothing happens?

Comment: what is the .ujpartner_ceges before the getElementById?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, I would use document.getElementById without the "ujpartner_ceges."

and the main problem is that your inputs don't have IDs, if you use the IDs exactly like the names your function will work as intended.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it. But i still get an error: TypeError: document.ujpartner_ceg.getElementById is not a function

Comment: i told you to remove the "ujpartner_ceg" ;)

Comment: use document.getElementById()

not document.ujpartner_ceg.getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem: `onclick="felhasznal(this)"`

But your function takes no parameter...

`function felhasznal() {`

Add a parameter to function:

`function felhasznal(myCheckbox) {`

or

remove the `this` from the `onclick` handler.

Answer (score -1):

your hidden input has no ID just a name.

use `<input type="hidden" id="felhasznalas" value="">` instead.

The ID must be unique for the DOM (page) not just the form, so if you have several forms you must prefix the control eg: `<input type="hidden" id="form1_felhasznalas" value="">`.

Then use document.getElementById instead of document.ujpartner_ceges.getElementById.

I would also take a couple of hours to learn [jquery](http://jquery.com/), it's an amazing javascript-cross-browser-framework / helper for doing things like this :) !

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3AguQ/
I have changed the hidden inputs to text so you can se the results...

Here is some code:

```
<script>
  function felhasznal(prefix)
  {
    document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value = '|x|';

    if (document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznal_1').checked)
    {
      document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value = document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value + '1|x|';
    }

    if (document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznal_2').checked)
    {
      document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value = document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value + '2|x|';
    }

    if (document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznal_3').checked)
    {
      document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value = document.getElementById(prefix + '_felhasznalas').value + '3|x|';
    }
  }      
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" id="form1_felhasznalas" value="">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_1" id="form1_felhasznal_1" onclick="felhasznal('form1')">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_2" id="form1_felhasznal_2" onclick="felhasznal('form1')">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_3" id="form1_felhasznal_3" onclick="felhasznal('form1')">
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" id="form2_felhasznalas" value="">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_1" id="form2_felhasznal_1" onclick="felhasznal('form2')">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_2" id="form2_felhasznal_2" onclick="felhasznal('form2')">
   <input type="checkbox" name="felhasznal_3" id="form2_felhasznal_3" onclick="felhasznal('form2')">
</form>
```